# Can't open a file in C/C++ using eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I have a medium size program I'm developing using eclipse, I can't show the content because it would be too large. At some point I have some lines of `fopen`, I'm basically trying to create a new file and printing inside such file a content that has been derived from some processing.

So my line is something like a classic

```
FILE* f = fopen(filename,"w");
```

where `filename` is a char array large enough. However the `FILE*` returned is 0, and when I check the `errno` it is number `2`, which means that the file doesn't exists.

However that's the point, I was trying to create a new file.
Is there something you could suggest that can I further check?

It's worth to note I'm running this stuff on unix, not windows.

Answer (score 1):

Is the value of filename an absolute path or a relative one? If it's the latter, then probably the process you run hasn't the cwd (current working directory) you think it has.

1. Try using an absolute path, if that works then
2. use the chdir system call at the begin of main to set the cwd

Comment: It is a relative path, what do you suggest?

Comment: as I said, the relative path is calculated from the 'current working directory' of the process. For a command line executed process, this is the directory where you are when you launch it. For programs executed from an environment (either the Eclipse IDE or a window manager of any sort) it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename might be incorrectly built, or you have no access to the path, or parts of the path don't exist.

Try a simple and clearly legal path first, like `C:\\Temp\\x.x` or something similar. if this works, it is not your code, but the filename.